# jQuery on click with namespace function

Tags: jquery, binding, onclick, namespaces, click

**How come this is illegal in jQuery?**

```
$('#someElm').on('click', customNamespace.namespaceFunction);
```

jQuery throws this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

**Note: The functions do not matter... but for illustration purposes:**

```
function customNamespace(){};

customNamespace.namespaceFunction = function(){ alert('do something'); };
```

The example above works... but how come when we bind to the document it does not
http://jsfiddle.net/2acrL/

Comment: what is `customNamespace.namespaceFunction`

Comment: And what is it's scope in relation to the bind statement? I do this all the time `$('.selector').on('events', app.fn);`.

Comment: looks like you miss it with the term namespace of event.

Comment: That works: http://jsfiddle.net/KquuK/

Comment: No! No! You want to do it this way: `var customNamespace = {}; customNamespace.namespaceFunction = function() { alert('do something'); };` and `customNamespace` has to be in the same or higher scope as the bind.

Comment: What do you mean by "bind to the document"? Can you show us the code that does not work?

Comment: user3558931 see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2acrL/

Comment: your demo works OK http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/2acrL/1/ you have not added jQuery for it.

Comment: Correct this version with jQuery works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/2acrL/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Turns out I was an idiot...**

namespaceFunction was spelled incorrectly (namespaceFunciton) in my code.

I wish jQuery would tell you `'namespaceFunciton' is not a function of 'customNamespace'` instead of just saying `"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"`

Comment: well, that kind of feature is not such easy to implement, you may like the error notification/logging system in .NET environment, everything is clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would want to do it:

```
$(function() {
    function customNamespace() {}; 
    customNamespace.namespaceFunction = function() { alert('do something'); };
    $('#someElm').on('click', customNamespace.namespaceFunction);
});
```

**Did you forget to include jQuery? See [Updated JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/2acrL/2/)**

**EDIT**

Edited to initialize `customNamespace` as a function.

**EDIT TWO**

The following code and demo shows the code working with event delegation and the same scoping as above:

```
$(function() {
    function customNamespace(){};

    customNamespace.namespaceFunction = function(){ alert('do something'); };

    $(document).on('click.blah', '[test-attr]' , customNamespace.namespaceFunction);
});
```

[**NEW JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/2acrL/3/)

Comment: Why initialize customNamespace as an object instead of a function? Also, why not define it as a global variable?

Comment: Yes, I'll initialize it as a function - will edit shortly. However, since it's use will be confined within DOM ready, the current scope is just fine. If you want to use inline JS such as onclick - which I would discourage - then it can be defined in the global scope.

Comment: It's not advisable to clutter the global scope unnecessarily.